# Getting hierarchial table element into xml format in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I have two tables one for the codes and other is the child mapping table to represent a parent child relation with the codes table.

Table: Codes

```
Code ID    |  Code Value  |  code Group | code Desc
1             Person 1       Accounts     cashier
2             Person 2       Finance      teller
3             Person 3       HR           administrator
4             Person 4       IT           system admin
```

Table: mapping

```
Id (Primarykey)       | code ID  | Parent Code ID   (both code ID and parent code ID are foreign keys with codes table
1                     1          Null
2                     2          1
3                     3          1
4                     4          Null
5                     3          4
```

I need a output as

```
<Codes>
<CodeParent group = "Accounts">
    <ChildCodes group= "Finance">
       <CodeParent name = "person 2" desc = "teller"/>
    </ChildCodes>
    <ChildCodes group = "HR">
       <CodeParent name = "Person 3" desc = "Administrator"/>
    <ChildCodes>    
</CodeParent >
<CodeParent group = "IT>
    <ChildCodes group = "HR">
       <CodeParent name = "Person 3" desc = "Administrator"/>
    <ChildCodes> 
</CodeParent >
</Root>
```

I tried using this SQL function but it doesn't seem to give the correct desired output

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetPartsSubTree(@PartNumberID int)
RETURNS XML
BEGIN RETURN
(SELECT codeMappingTable.codeID AS "@codeID",
codes.codeLiteral AS "@codeLiteral",
codes.codeGroup AS "@codeGroup",
dbo.GetPartsSubTree(codeMappingTable.codeID)
FROM codeMappingTable,codes

WHERE codeMappingTable.ParentcodeID=@PartNumberID and codes.codeID = codeMappingTable.codeID
ORDER BY codeMappingTable.codeID
FOR XML PATH('CodeParent'),ROOT('ChildCodes'),TYPE)
END

GO

SELECT codeMappingTable.codeID AS "@codeID",
codes.codeLiteral AS "@codeLiteral",
codes.codeGroup AS "@codeGroup",
dbo.GetPartsSubTree(codeMappingTable.codeID)
FROM codeMappingTable,codes
WHERE codeMappingTable.ParentcodeID is null and codes.codeID = codeMappingTable.codeID
ORDER BY codeMappingTable.codeID
FOR XML PATH('CodeParent'),ROOT('Codes'),TYPE
```

Please help me on this.

The expected output in a bigger scale is as below:

```
<Codes>
  <codeGroup codeGroup="Entity">
    <CodeParent codeID="18" codeDesc="Borrower" codeGroup="Entity">
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type">
        <CodeParent codeID="20" codeDesc="Financial Statement - Annual" codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type" />
        <CodeParent codeID="21" codeDesc="Tax Returns" codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type" />
      </ChildCodes>
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="Covenant Type">
        <CodeParent codeID="24" codeDesc="Capital Expenditures" codeGroup="Covenant Type" />
        <CodeParent codeID="25" codeDesc="Cash Flow Coverage Ratio" codeGroup="Covenant Type" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
    <CodeParent codeID="17" codeDesc="Guarantor" codeGroup="Entity">
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type">
        <CodeParent codeID="20" codeDesc="Financial Statement - Annual" codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type" />
        <CodeParent codeID="22" codeDesc="Brokerage Statements" codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type" />
      </ChildCodes>
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="Covenant Type">
        <CodeParent codeID="27" codeDesc="Current Ratio" codeGroup="Covenant Type" />
        <CodeParent codeID="28" codeDesc="Debt Service Coverage Ratio" codeGroup="Covenant Type" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
  </codeGroup>
  <codeGroup codeGroup="Entity Category">
    <CodeParent codeID="4" codeDesc="Company" codeGroup="Entity Category">
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type">
        <CodeParent codeID="9" codeDesc="American Subsidiary or Agency of Japanese TR Co" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type">
          <ChildCodes codeGroup="test type">
            <CodeParent codeID="29" codeDesc="xyz" codeGroup="test type" />
            <CodeParent codeID="30" codeDesc="www" codeGroup="test type" />
          </ChildCodes>
        </CodeParent>
        <CodeParent codeID="11" codeDesc="Cooperative" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
        <CodeParent codeID="13" codeDesc="Corporation" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
    <CodeParent codeID="8" codeDesc="Individual" codeGroup="Entity Category">
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type">
        <CodeParent codeID="1" codeDesc="US Bancorp Employee" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
        <CodeParent codeID="3" codeDesc="US Bancorp Officer" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
    <CodeParent codeID="5" codeDesc="LLC" codeGroup="Entity Category" />
    <CodeParent codeID="6" codeDesc="Trust" codeGroup="Entity Category">
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type">
        <CodeParent codeID="1" codeDesc="US Bancorp Employee" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
  </codeGroup>
  <codeGroup codeGroup="Category">
    <CodeParent codeID="31" codeDesc="cat1" codeGroup="Category" />
    <CodeParent codeID="32" codeDesc="cat2" codeGroup="Category" />
    <CodeParent codeID="33" codeDesc="cat3" codeGroup="Category" />
  </codeGroup>
  <codeGroup codeGroup="Facility">
    <CodeParent codeID="34" codeDesc="cat1" codeGroup="Facility" >
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="BorrowerType">
        <CodeParent codeID="40" codeDesc="Employee" codeGroup="BorrowerType" />
        <CodeParent codeID="41" codeDesc="Officer" codeGroup="BorrowerType" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
    <CodeParent codeID="35" codeDesc="cat2" codeGroup="Facility" />
    <CodeParent codeID="36" codeDesc="cat3" codeGroup="Facility" />
  </codeGroup>
  <codeGroup codeGroup="Loan">
    <CodeParent codeID="37" codeDesc="cat1" codeGroup="Loan" >
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="BorrowerType">
        <CodeParent codeID="40" codeDesc="Employee" codeGroup="BorrowerType" />
        <CodeParent codeID="41" codeDesc="Officer" codeGroup="BorrowerType" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
    <CodeParent codeID="38" codeDesc="cat2" codeGroup="Loan" />
    <CodeParent codeID="39" codeDesc="cat3" codeGroup="Loan" />
  </codeGroup>
</Codes>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Codes table(ID int, CodeValue varchar(10), CodeGroup varchar(10), CodeDesc varchar(20))
declare @Mapping table(ID int, CodeID int, ParentCodeID int)

insert into @Codes values
(1, 'Person 1', 'Accounts', 'cashier'),
(2, 'Person 2', 'Finance',  'teller'),
(3, 'Person 3', 'HR',       'administrator'),
(4, 'Person 4', 'IT',       'system admin'),
(5, 'Person 5', 'Accounts', 'accountant'),
(6, 'Person 6', 'Finance', 'Investbanker')

insert into @Mapping values
(1, 1, null),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1),
(4, 4, null),
(5, 3, 4),
(6, 5, null),
(7, 6, 1)

select
  CRoot.CodeGroup as '@group',
  (select 
     CChild.CodeGroup as '@group',
     CChild.CodeValue as 'CodeParent/@name',
     CChild.CodeDesc as 'CodeParent/@desc'
   from @Mapping as MChild
    inner join @Codes as CChild
      on MChild.CodeID = CChild.ID
   where MChild.ParentCodeID = MRoot.ID
   for xml path('ChildCodes'), type)
from @Mapping as MRoot
  inner join @Codes as CRoot
    on MRoot.CodeID = CRoot.ID
where
  MRoot.ParentCodeID is null
for xml path('CodeParent'), root('Codes')
```

Result

```
<Codes>
  <CodeParent group="Accounts">
    <ChildCodes group="Finance">
      <CodeParent name="Person 2" desc="teller" />
    </ChildCodes>
    <ChildCodes group="HR">
      <CodeParent name="Person 3" desc="administrator" />
    </ChildCodes>
    <ChildCodes group="Finance">
      <CodeParent name="Person 6" desc="Investbanker" />
    </ChildCodes>
  </CodeParent>
  <CodeParent group="IT">
    <ChildCodes group="HR">
      <CodeParent name="Person 3" desc="administrator" />
    </ChildCodes>
  </CodeParent>
  <CodeParent group="Accounts" />
</Codes>
```

Comment: I tried your code Mikael, It works however when I have more nested entries in the tables it fails to handle it for example see below

Comment: I tried your code Mikael, It works however when I have more nested entries in the tables it fails to handle it for example see below insert into @Codes 
values (5, 'Person 5', 'Accounts', 'accountant')
insert into @Codes 
values (6, 'Person 6', 'Finance',  'Investbanker')
insert into @Mapping values  (6, 5, null)
insert into @Mapping values  (7, 6, 1)
It creates multiple nodes for accounts and multiple nodes for finance

Comment: @Hema - Updated answer with your new data. You added one new root item `accounts` and on new item under the first `accounts` node `Finance`. Is that not what you want?. If not, please update your question with the input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Mikael, I have the following possible relationships in the above tables
1) The parent code group is all by itself.
2) The parent code group drives a single child group
3) The parent code group drives two different child groups
4) The parent code group drives a child and the child group inturn drives a sub-child group
5) A child group is having two different parent groups

Here is the below code output desired when all the relationships exist.

```
    <Codes>
      <codeGroup codeGroup="Entity">
        <CodeParent codeID="18" codeDesc="Borrower" codeGroup="Entity">
          <ChildCodes codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type">
            <CodeParent codeID="20" codeDesc="Financial Statement - Annual" codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type" />
            <CodeParent codeID="21" codeDesc="Tax Returns" codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type" />
          </ChildCodes>
          <ChildCodes codeGroup="Covenant Type">
            <CodeParent codeID="24" codeDesc="Capital Expenditures" codeGroup="Covenant Type" />
            <CodeParent codeID="25" codeDesc="Cash Flow Coverage Ratio" codeGroup="Covenant Type" />
          </ChildCodes>
        </CodeParent>
        <CodeParent codeID="17" codeDesc="Guarantor" codeGroup="Entity">
          <ChildCodes codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type">
            <CodeParent codeID="20" codeDesc="Financial Statement - Annual" codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type" />
            <CodeParent codeID="22" codeDesc="Brokerage Statements" codeGroup="Fin Reporting Type" />
          </ChildCodes>
          <ChildCodes codeGroup="Covenant Type">
            <CodeParent codeID="27" codeDesc="Current Ratio" codeGroup="Covenant Type" />
            <CodeParent codeID="28" codeDesc="Debt Service Coverage Ratio" codeGroup="Covenant Type" />
          </ChildCodes>
        </CodeParent>
      </codeGroup>
      <codeGroup codeGroup="Entity Category">
        <CodeParent codeID="4" codeDesc="Company" codeGroup="Entity Category">
          <ChildCodes codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type">
            <CodeParent codeID="9" codeDesc="American Subsidiary or Agency of Japanese TR Co" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type">
              <ChildCodes codeGroup="test type">
                <CodeParent codeID="29" codeDesc="xyz" codeGroup="test type" />
                <CodeParent codeID="30" codeDesc="www" codeGroup="test type" />
              </ChildCodes>
            </CodeParent>
            <CodeParent codeID="11" codeDesc="Cooperative" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
            <CodeParent codeID="13" codeDesc="Corporation" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
          </ChildCodes>
        </CodeParent>
        <CodeParent codeID="8" codeDesc="Individual" codeGroup="Entity Category">
          <ChildCodes codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type">
            <CodeParent codeID="1" codeDesc="US Bancorp Employee" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
            <CodeParent codeID="3" codeDesc="US Bancorp Officer" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
          </ChildCodes>
        </CodeParent>
        <CodeParent codeID="5" codeDesc="LLC" codeGroup="Entity Category" />
        <CodeParent codeID="6" codeDesc="Trust" codeGroup="Entity Category">
          <ChildCodes codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type">
            <CodeParent codeID="1" codeDesc="US Bancorp Employee" codeGroup="AFS Obligor Type" />
          </ChildCodes>
        </CodeParent>
      </codeGroup>
      <codeGroup codeGroup="Category">
        <CodeParent codeID="31" codeDesc="cat1" codeGroup="Category" />
        <CodeParent codeID="32" codeDesc="cat2" codeGroup="Category" />
        <CodeParent codeID="33" codeDesc="cat3" codeGroup="Category" />
      </codeGroup>
      <codeGroup codeGroup="Facility">
          <CodeParent codeID="34" codeDesc="cat1" codeGroup="Facility" >
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="BorrowerType">
        <CodeParent codeID="40" codeDesc="Employee" codeGroup="BorrowerType" />
        <CodeParent codeID="41" codeDesc="Officer" codeGroup="BorrowerType" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
    <CodeParent codeID="35" codeDesc="cat2" codeGroup="Facility" />
    <CodeParent codeID="36" codeDesc="cat3" codeGroup="Facility" />
  </codeGroup>
  <codeGroup codeGroup="Loan">
    <CodeParent codeID="37" codeDesc="cat1" codeGroup="Loan" >
      <ChildCodes codeGroup="BorrowerType">
        <CodeParent codeID="40" codeDesc="Employee" codeGroup="BorrowerType" />
        <CodeParent codeID="41" codeDesc="Officer" codeGroup="BorrowerType" />
      </ChildCodes>
    </CodeParent>
    <CodeParent codeID="38" codeDesc="cat2" codeGroup="Loan" />
    <CodeParent codeID="39" codeDesc="cat3" codeGroup="Loan" />
  </codeGroup>
    </Codes>
```